# Django - referencing static files in templates

Tags: python, django, templates, twitter-bootstrap, static

I'm having difficulty referencing static files in my templates. I am using Twitter Bootstrap and have the bootstrap files (css, img, js) sitting at mysite/static.

I have set the `STATIC_URL`, `STATIC_ROOT` and `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS` according to [this tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/#staticfiles-in-templates). I have run `./manage.py collectstatic` which copied 72 files over. I have also added the below template tag to my template (`index.html`) file but this hasn't worked.

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static user_stylesheet %}" type="text/css" media="screen"/>
```

Any help on how to reference the files so that the bootstrap styling returns to the templates would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It should be

```
{% load static %}
```

And then something like

```
<!-- path -->
<link href="{% static 'bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css' %}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<!--->
```

**Update for Completeness**

*Folder Structure*

- proj
- app1
- app2
- myproj_public
- static

  - css

    - bootstrap.css
  - js

    - xyz.js

*Settings File*

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.abspath(
    os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'myproj_public', 'static')), '')

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

Comment: Thanks. I have added this to the top of my index.html file but this hasn't worked. Is there something else I could have missed?

Comment: What does it say when you inspect your page in firebug (firefox) or developer tools (chrome). Do you have the css files in the right directory?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I finally got it working after fixing the path to the static files.

Comment: Is this solution still current? I am using Django 1.8.6 and this is not working for me. My directory structure is very similar.

Comment: No, it seems out of date. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/static-files/

Answer (score 5):

Are you setting the `user_stylesheet` context variable in your view? You need to set that before you can pass it onto templates.

I usually just use the `{{ static_url }}` tag for doing this stuff, so my code for including bootstrap components would be like.

```
<link href="{{ STATIC_URL }}bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
<script src="{{ STATIC_URL }}bootstrap/js/jquery.js"></script>
```

Assuming that bootstrap folder is present inside static.

EDIT

For your case, to set `user_stylesheet` context variable, you'll need to do something like

```
dict["user_stylesheet"]= <path to your file>
#add other context variables you might have to
render_to_response(<your template name>, dict, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Comment: Thanks @ersran9. I haven't set the user_stylesheet context variable in views.py. This is all new territory at the moment so I'm not quite sure what to set it as. What would your user_stylesheet context variable read?

Comment: @Jess Edited the answer. Btw, if you are using static_url as I've shown, there is no need to set the user_stylesheet, setting the proper static_root and static_url in settings.py is enough

Comment: OK, thank you. I have set the static_root and static_url in settings.py and added the code as recommended by super9 below to the top of index.html but this hasn't worked. Is there anything else I could be doing wrong?

Comment: @Jess Try printing the `{{ STATIC_URL }}` in your template - check if it set to the right url. Once you confirm that, try requesting a file directly through the browser,ie: 127.0.0.1:8000/<static_url>/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css to check whether `{{ STATIC_ROOT }}` is set properly

Answer (score 0):

When you set `static_root`, for example:

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static_root/")
```

, all files are copied there, instead of in `project_root/static`. It is a new mechanism introduced in Django 1.3, to easy the static file processing: it will collect all files in each `STATICFILES_DIR` *and all `static` dir under each installed app*, so you copy them once in all.

Refer the css/js files with `static_root` path.