# Django: Decouple the dependency between statics files

Tags: django, dependencies, static-files

Django has provided a nice solution to dependency problems concerning with urls, say `reverse` function in views, or `{% static %}` in template. Can I use some same approach to deal with static files? For example, I have a css in /static/css and a image in /static/img and I want to add something in css like `background: url({% static 'img/XXX' %})`

Comment: Something like this: https://github.com/peterbe/django-static ?

Comment: This could help you too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14013436/django-referencing-static-files-in-templates

Comment: django static tags are automatically reversed in django 1.5.1

Comment: Thanks, django-static might work, but it is rather old, and I fear it won't be compatible with current Django version. And I don't want to plug in too many apps, cause it's hard to manage. Isn't there a nicer solution?

Comment: @user1606453: What is your django version then?

Comment: Games: I'm afraid you might misunderstand my intention. I want to use static tags in a static file(like css), not in templates.

Comment: @user1606453: Well, that is a really bad idea. Why not use pre-processed lanugaes like SASS or LESS instead to accomplish the same thing?

Comment: Wow, I've never heard anything like SASS or LESS. It seems to fit perfectly. Yeah, using dynamic elements in a static file is bad. Thanks.