# Bluemix Cloud Foundry, Referencing static files in Django

Tags: python, django, ibm-cloud, django-staticfiles

I am attempting to learn Django development with Bluemix Cloud Foundry and Python 3.5.3.

I have a hello world Website running at this time.  But I cannot get static files like CSS to be served.

I think my settings for finding static files are not correct.

---

My served page is meant to look like:

[image: correct result]

What I am getting is:

[image: actual result]

---

I get the correct result locally with `Debug = True` in settings.py, but not with `Debug = False`. I cannot get the correct result when pushed to Bluemix, regardless of the Debug setting.

My project folders are set up like this:

[image: Project Folder Structure]

the django staticfiles app is in my Installed_Apps variable.

In my settings.py file I have:

```
...
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
# STATICFILES_DIRS = [
#     os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'bluemixsite/static'),
#     os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'bluemixapp/static'),
# ]
```

STATICFILES_DIRS appeared to make no difference with finding static files.

The template page (being loaded) includes the following:

```
...
{% load static %}

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'bluemixapp/stylesheet.css' %}" />
</head>
....
```

With Debug=False, when inspected in firefox, I can see this message under the style editor both locally and on bluemix:

```
The requested URL /static/bluemixapp/stylesheet.css was not found on this server.
```

So either I do not have the files in the correct location, or Django cannot resolve paths to the static files on the server.

---

I tried the collectstatic command which copied all static files into `project_root/static/` folder but this made no difference.

Apparently Bluemix refuses to run linux terminals (they freeze or crash when starting) so I can't do anything at the server end that way.

I cannot load the static files onto a separate server.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try Loading static from static files instead:

`{% load static from staticfiles %}`

As mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14013436/django-referencing-static-files-in-templates).

Answer (score 0):

You need to run the command
`python manage.py collectstatic`
in your src directory in the development framework. (In the folder containing the manage.py file)
This will construct a folder containing all your static files in a manner accessible in your production app.
For further information you can follow this free tutorial:
https://www.coursera.org/lecture/developing-applications-with-sql-databases-and-django/manage-static-files-QGe9i